# Вызов функции по клику

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Имеется функция, которая вызывает при нажатии на div content.

```
function selectText(elementId) {

    var doc = document,
        text = doc.getElementById(elementId),
        range,
        selection;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

$("#content").click(function() {
    selectText(this.id);
    document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызывать ту же самую функцию, но только при нажатии на кнопку? И чтобы копирование происходило в пределах заданного дива.

Comment: Какая кнопка? Кнопка клавиатуры?

Comment: Нет, css кнопка.

Comment: Просто создай отдельно функцию и запускай ее от туда от куда хочешь

Comment: Так у тебя уже есть пример вызова функции по клику

Comment: тут вызов функции при нажатии на id content, а не при нажатии на кнопку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function selectText(elementId) {
  var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(elementId),
    range,
    selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}

$("#content").click(function() {
  selectText(this.id);
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#content").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">some test text...</div>
<br />
<button>select</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручил. Весь день голову ломаю.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте код:

```
$("#здесь id кнопки").click(function() {
    //здесь код, который определяет нужный id diva
    selectText(здесь id diva, который Вас интересует);
    document.execCommand("copy");
});`
```

Думаю, должно сработать

Comment: Вы предлагаете в месте, где определяется область для копирования, вставить id кнопки. Это не верное решение.

Comment: @alta, согласен - код требует правки. Исправил

Comment: предложенный вариант не работает